# Broadcasting over batch dimension in matmul properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

So im trying to multiply two tensors `A` and `B` where `A = [1, n, n*2]` and `B = [bs, n*2, m]` which should result in `C = [64, n, m]`.

In my mind this should be as easy as `tf.matmul(A,B)` where it should broadcast over the batch dimension.

I get the error:

> Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 64 for
>   'seq2seq/decoder/attention/MatMul' (op: 'BatchMatMul') with input
>   shapes: [1,256,512], [64,512,120]

I have also tried `tf.multiply` (which should support broadcasting) but with same error.

A simple dirty hack would be:

```
tf.stack([tf.matmul(A, s) for s in tf.unstack(B, axis=0)], axis=0)
```

But this seems rather horrible.
I see a lot answers with using `tf.reshape`, which, from previous experience, I would like to avoid. Other answers suggest `tf.einsum` but I have never worked with that before and I cant help but to think there must be an easier solution to this problem.

So I guess my question is what my best options for getting around the dirty hack in the best way.

Thanks

Comment: you can use A = tf.tile(A, [bs]) then A = tf.reshape(A, (bs, n, n*2)). Is this also something you wish to avoid?

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't support broadcasting in `tf.matmul`. I think your best bet is to use `tf.einsum`. Try `C = tf.einsum('ink,bkm->bnm', A, B)`. I hadn't used it before either, but at least the syntax makes some sense when read off: inputs have shape `[i, n, k]` and `[b, k, m]`, and output has shape `[b, n, m]`.

Comment: I want to avoid reshape since I dont really feel comfortable how the elements of the tensors are put back together. Ill probably go for the einsum solution :)
Thanks for the fast answers :)